# Laravel 10 WithoutEvents trait throws unable to disable events error

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

My application depends heavily on events. However, many of my tests don't require events, so I rely on the `\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutEvents` trait to disable them. In migrating to Laravel 10 from 9, my tests are throwing "Unable to disable events. ApplicationTrait not used."

I created a fresh Laravel 10 install and added the WithoutEvents trait to the example feature test:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

// use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutEvents;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithoutEvents;

    /**
     * A basic test example.
     */
    public function test_the_application_returns_a_successful_response(): void
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

Running the tests with `vendor/bin/phunit` returns:

```
Time: 00:00.138, Memory: 22.00 MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Feature\ExampleTest::test_the_application_returns_a_successful_response
Exception: Unable to disable events. ApplicationTrait not used.
```

If I do the same in a fresh Laravel 9 install, the test runs fine. Any idea what's going on here? FWIW, I'm on PHP 8.1.11 and composer 2.5.4.

Comment: Can you show your TestCase? The code of the trait didn't change between 9 -> 10.

Comment: No change to TestCase -- just a fresh install for both 9 and 10. The only thing I did was install and modify ExampleTest then run phpunit.

Comment: Does your testcase extend Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase? If so, they removed the MocksApplicationServices trait which contained the withoutEvents() function. I am not sure where this function went, but if the function cannot be found, the error that you found will occur...

Comment: If you add this function to your TestCase, do your tests run?
  https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MocksApplicationServices.php#L101

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade#service-mocking the upgrade guide has this in it

Comment: Thanks so much! I totally missed it in the guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It throws the exception because as Aless55 points out in the comments to the question, the MocksApplicationServices trait which included `protected function withoutEvents()` has been removed from `\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase`. When the `WithoutEvents` trait can't find this method, it throws the error.

The guide is not clear that if you use WithoutEvents (which has not been removed from the framework), you need to move to using `Event::fake()` in setUp() or in your individual tests. See the upgrade guide: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade#service-mocking